# I want to create a function that takes a text string and returns a dictionary containing certain characters with how many tmies they occur

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This is what I have so far as a function

```
example = "Sample String"

def func(text, let):
    count= {}
    for let in text.lower():
        let = count.keys()
        if let in text:
            count[let] += 1
        else:
            count[let] = 1
    return count
```

I want to return something like this

```
print(func(example, "sao"))

{'s': 2, 'a' : 1}
```

I am not very sure what I could improve on

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Counter` from the `collections` built-in module:

```
from collections import Counter

def func(text, let):
     c = Counter(text.lower())
     return {l: c[l] for l in let if l in c.keys()}
```

**Breaking it down**:

`Counter` will return the count of letters in your string:

```
In [5]: Counter(example.lower())
Out[5]: 
Counter({'s': 2,
         'a': 1,
         'm': 1,
         'p': 1,
         'l': 1,
         'e': 1,
         ' ': 1,
         't': 1,
         'r': 1,
         'i': 1,
         'n': 1,
         'g': 1})
```

So then all you need to do is return a dictionary of the appropriate letters, which can be done in a dictionary comprehension:

```
# iterate over every letter in `let`, and get the Counter value for that letter, 
# if that letter is in the Counter keys
{l: c[l] for l in let if l in c.keys()}
```

**Fixing your code**

If you prefer to use your approach, you could make your code work properly with this:

```
def func(text, let):
    count = {}
    for l in text.lower():
        if l in let:
            if l in count.keys():
                count[l] += 1
            else:
                count[l] = 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from functools import reduce

def count(text, letters):
    return reduce(
        lambda d, letr: d.update({letr: d.get(letr, 0) + 1}) or d,
        filter(lambda l: l in letters, text), {}
    )
```

Read it backwards.

Creates an empty dictionary.

```py
{}
```

Filters letters from text.

```py
lambda l: l in letters
```

This lambda function returns true if l is in letters

```py
filter(lambda l: l in letters, text)
```

reduce will iterate over the object returned by filter, which will
only produce letters in text, if they are in letters.

```py
lambda d, letr: d.update({letr: d.get(letr, 0) + 1}) or d
```

Updates the dictionary with the count of the letters it encounters.
Each time reduce iterates over an item generated by the filter object,
it will call this lambda function. Since `dict.update() -> None`, returns None, which evaluates to `false`, we say `or d` to actually return the dict back to reduce, which will pass the dict back into the lambda the next time it gets called, thus building up the counts. We also use `dict.get()` in the lambda instead of `d[i]`, this allows us to pass the default of `0` if the letter is not yet in the dictionary.

At the end reduce returns the dict, and we return that from count.
This is similar to how "map reduce" works.

You can read about [functional style and lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=lambda) expressions in the python docs.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> def func(text: str, let: str):
...     text, count = text.lower(), {}
...     for i in let:
...         if text.count(i) != 0:
...             count[i] = text.count(i)
...     return count
...
>>> print(func("Sample String", "sao"))
{'s': 2, 'a': 1}
```